# My SQL SELECT ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

[image]

Can some one explain this error. According to me every thing is fine but still error. Help me.

Comment: Explain the error?  I can't even read it.

Comment: The problem is that flowing query command work fine. It return all record with my php code. "SELECT * FROM `settings`;" But I want to  extract record base on the key field in my setting table. like this SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE key=`flatFee`; But this give error. I believe this is correct sql Syntax but still giving error. I am using wapmserver for my local environment.

Comment: @MuhammadShaaban Look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing a string you should use -> `'` and not -> ` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `settings`
WHERE key = 'flatFee'
```